# Remove blank lines from output?

Tags: powershell

When I run this command, it returns the output with lots of blank lines.

```
Get-Host | Select Name, Version | Format-List
```

I tried using `ExpandProperty` but it still leaves me with one blank line at the end of the output, is there a way to remove the last blank line?

```
Get-Host | Select -ExpandProperty Name, Version | Format-List
```

Comment: Why you need to remove them? Do you want to log the output into file or just to show it on the console?

Comment: What do you call blank line? Empty line in the console or a property that has no value?

Comment: I'm using this output in another script

Comment: Please be more specific, your problem is unclear you should provide an image or code of the ouput as it appears in your console to show others what's the real problem.

Comment: Don't use `Format-List` then, if you use the output somewhere else. Use `ConvertTo-Csv` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need the format that `Format-List` provides, then you can use `Out-String` and Trim() to get rid of empty lines:

```
Get-Host | Select Name,Version | Format-List | Out-String | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

But, depending on your needs, it's probably easier to just use CSV or the JSON format for further processing (see `ConvertTo-Json` or `ConvertTo-Csv`).