# Remove blank lines from the output

Tags: powershell, output

I have this script:

```
for ( ; $true ; )
{
    Write-Host ""
    Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    ping -n 1 10.10.50.203 | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Pinging" -Context 1,2
    ping -n 1 10.10.50.201 | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Pinging" -Context 1,2
    timeout 5 > null
}
```

It produces this output:

```
2018-08-29 14:40:49


> Pinging 10.10.50.203 with 32 bytes of data:
  Request timed out.


> Pinging 10.10.50.201 with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 10.10.50.201: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=126

2018-08-29 14:40:54

> Pinging 10.10.50.203 with 32 bytes of data:
  Request timed out.


> Pinging 10.10.50.201 with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 10.10.50.201: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=126
```

We need it without the empty lines:

```
2018-08-29 14:40:49
> Pinging 10.10.50.203 with 32 bytes of data:
  Request timed out.
> Pinging 10.10.50.201 with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 10.10.50.201: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=126

2018-08-29 14:40:54
> Pinging 10.10.50.203 with 32 bytes of data:
  Request timed out.
> Pinging 10.10.50.201 with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 10.10.50.201: bytes=32 time=58ms TTL=126
```

I was trying solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252707/remove-blank-lines-in-powershell-output) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453079/remove-blank-lines-from-output) questions but nothing helps.

Especially the `| ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }` solution produces this error message:

> ... does not contain a method named 'Trim'.

**PS Version:**

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.17134.165
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.165
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Since you're using PowerShell, try to alter your script to use the PowerShell command Test-NetConnection instead of ping. It will return an usable PowerShell object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine.

```
for ( ; $true ; )
{
    Write-Host ""
    Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    (ping -n 1 www.google.com | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Pinging" -Context 1,2 | Out-String).Trim()
    (ping -n 1 www.google.co.in | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Pinging" -Context 1,2 | Out-String).Trim()
    timeout 5 > null
}
```

Output :

```
2018-08-29 18:42:10
> Pinging www.google.com [216.58.197.36] with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 216.58.197.36: bytes=32 time=21ms TTL=53
> Pinging www.google.co.in [216.58.197.35] with 32 bytes of data:
  Reply from 216.58.197.35: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=57
```

Answer (score 0):

> Especially the | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() } solution produces this error message:
>
> ... does not contain a method named 'Trim'.

I'm guessing that was because you didn't use

```
out-string |
```

before the ForEach?

i.e.

```
*some-command* | out-string | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `` -replace "`n",'' `` to remove empty lines. This can be particularly useful when wanting to keep whitespace in e.g. indented lines that Trim() method otherwise will remove. Often there is no need for `Out-String` eiher.

In this example the code would be:

```
for ( ; $true ; )
{
    Write-Host ""
    Get-Date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    (ping -n 1 10.10.50.203 | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Pinging" -Context 1,2) -replace "`n",''
    (ping -n 1 10.10.50.201 | Select-String -SimpleMatch "Pinging" -Context 1,2) -replace "`n",''
    timeout 5 > $null
}
```