# Powershell WMI-Object Select-Object makes 2 blank lines, is there a way to remove the blank lines?

Tags: string, windows, list, powershell

I'm making a list of infomation that i what to display.
But anytime i run the line that is needed to show the info, it's gonna place 2 blank lines over the output.

Code looks like this

```
$Pro = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor

$pro | select-Object Name,NumberofCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors | format-list
```

Is there something else i can do to make it remove the 2 lines from the output?
(Can't show the blank lines because they don't show)

```
Name : Intel(R)
NumberOfCores : x
NumberOfLogicalProcessors : x
```

Comment: the `Format-List` cmdlet is what is creating the two trailing blank lines. the simplest way to remove those 2 lines is to assign the output to a $Var & then use`$Var[0..2]`. ///// generally speaking, one should NOT use the `Format-*` cmdlets for anything other than _final_ output to a plain text file OR to the screen. so, if you intend to use the info later in your script, you likely otta avoid using those cmdlets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453079/remove-blank-lines-from-output) and [this2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252707/remove-blank-lines-in-powershell-output).  Most `Format-*` cmdlets have this quirk.

Comment: @leeharvey1 The first link that you provide "this1" had just what i needed to change it, thanks :)

$pro | Select-Object Name | Format-list| Out-string | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }

Comment: @Toppers - you are most welcome! glad to help a little ... [*grin*]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove blank lines from output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47453079/remove-blank-lines-from-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer from @leeharvey1 is what was needed.

```
$pro | Select-Object Name | Format-list| Out-string | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution i've could figure to overcome the blank lines issue:

```bsh
$Pro = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor

$pro | select-Object Name,NumberofCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors | format-list | Out-String | % ($_) {$_.Trim()}
```